# Разделение проекта под SVN

Tags: svn, репозиторий, tortoise-svn

Например есть основной проект (ОП). Дня него создан репозиторий, и все с ним прекрасно. Но с этого проекта нужно сделать 2 дочерних проекта.

В основном проекте файлы - уникальны. То есть файлы основного проекта в дочерних не изменяться, а в дочерних будут свои.

Вопрос. Можно как-нибудь настроить проект *дочернего*! проекта, чтоб можно было обновлять его с двоих репозиториев. Основные файлы с основного репозитория, и свой репозиторий.

Спасибо!

Comment: В svn же есть [external](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663155). Это не то, что нужно?

Comment: BOPOH, наверное Вы правы! Это то что мне нужно! Оформите как ответ! SVN использую недавно, и не знал о external! Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать внешние зависимости, то есть по сути несколько связанных репозиториев.

Данная статья должна Вам помочь:
http://elis.dvo.ru/~lab_11/svn-book-html-chunk/svn.advanced.externals.html

Answer (score 0):

Если все лежит на одном сервере, то использовать hook post-commit.

В проекте XXX, который использует проект YYY, сделать checkout проекта YYY, а в post-commit'e автоматизировать update.

Answer (score -1):

Для этого существуют ветки в SVN http://habrahabr.ru/post/120063/

Comment: Вопрос в другом был: есть две независимые ветки, причем одна из них используется во второй (как пакет, например). Необходимо при изменении первой ветки автоматически подхватывать изменения во второй ветке. Можно делать через merge, можно ручками заменять на новый код, но здесь, вроде, больше `externals` подходит - сорцы автоматически будут подтягиваться откуда надо. Есть еще варианты, например, для `php` через `composer` все оформлять и подтягивать необходимое, но `external` как бы проще будет, не надо лишних телодвижений делать

Comment: @BOPOH: Запили отдельный ответ! )

Comment: @SiZE Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Ответы ссылки не приветствуются сообществом. Добавьте описание того, что нужно сделать для решения задачи, приведите пример

Comment: Посмотрите англоязычную версию на тему ответов-ссылок. Какой смысл пересказывать или копипастить чужой материал, если можно дать его человеку и он с ним так же разберется или даже увидит еще что-то полезное для себя.